# How do I uninstall Visual C++ when it's not even installed and I can't get it to install?

Tags: installation

When I click on uninstall Visual C++ 2010 Express in control panel, it takes me to vc_web.exe which is web setup for installing it because it thinks it needs to install it first. Then when it is at 100% done installing, it gives an error that I forgot to write down. So what I'm doing now is just waiting for the vc_web.exe that I downloaded from the web site to see if that will install it.  If it does, I will

Comment: `If it does, I will` what? Also if the new installer doesn't do anything, **DO WRITE THE ERROR NUMBER DOWN! EVEN IF IT MAY SOUND COMPLETELY UNBELIEVABLE, THE ERROR NUMBERS MEAN SOMETHING.**. If you can't get to that point again, update the question. Also try running disk cleanup and delete the temporary files. In the worst case, you may have to clean the registry by hand if there are any pieces left in there.

Comment: Well, all I had to do was wait a long time and it finally uninstalled.  Took maybe 10 minutes.

Answer (score 2):

The [Visual Studio 2010 Uninstall Utility](http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/vs2010uninstall) should do the trick.

Make sure you run it with Administrator privileges.